# sas_ variable value inside a like in a macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I need to use the following code inse a macro:

```
proc sql;
select name
into :lista
separated by ' '
from dictionary.columns 
where libname='LABO2' 
and name like 't1_%'
and name like "%5";
quit;
```

But when I write:

```
%macro prue(numero);
proc sql;
select name
into :listas
separated by ' '
from dictionary.columns 
where libname='LABO2' 
and name like 't1_%'
and name like "% &numero.";
quit;
%put "% &numero";
%mend;

%prue(5);
```

I get in the like '% 5' when I need '%5'. If I delete the blanck space in

```
like "%&numero."
```

I don't get the variable value 5, I get '%&numero'. So I don't know how to solve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use macro quoting to escape the percent sign and/or to separate it from the macro variable.  One solution of many:

```
%let text=fred;

proc sql;
select name from sashelp.class
where name like "%nrstr(%%)&text.";
quit;
```

You double the `%` because the first % in a `%str` or `%nrstr` escapes certain characters, including percent itself.

Answer (score 0):

ok, this is not the best way to do it, but the solution would be to use the cats:

```
%let li=%sysfunc(cats(%,&numero));
```

and in the macro:

```
and name like "&li";
```

Do you know any other way to solve this????? is this the formal way to solve it?
thanks

Comment: You could use `name like cats("%","&numero")` directly in the sql statement instead of creating a new macro variable.

Comment: I don't know but I don't see any way it can get much simpler than that :)